# Why is my select value not being reset? Problem with "selected" attr/prop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

```js
var original_role = $('option:selected', '#user_role').val();

$('#role_cancel').click(function() {
//console.log(original_role);
  $('option:selected', '#user_role').removeAttr('selected'); //deselect current option
  $('#user_role').find('option[value="' + original_role + '"]').attr('selected'); //select original value
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <select name="user_role" class="form-control" id="user_role">
      <option value="0">Ninguno</option>
      <option value="1">Admin</option>
      <option value="24">Secretario general</option>
      <option value="25">SecretarioExcursiones</option>
      <option value="26">Tesorería</option>
      <option value="27">Almacen</option>
      <option value="28">Coordinador</option>
      <option value="30">Reta</option>
      <option value="31">Invitado</option>
      <option value="32" selected="">Prospecto</option>
      <option value="33">Presidente</option>
      <option value="34">Eventos especiales</option>
      <option value="36">Guía</option>
      <option value="37">Soci@</option>
      <option value="38">Inivtado</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <button id="role_cancel">
  RESET
  </button>
  
</div>
```

When pressing RESET, the select should

1. Remove selected attr/prop from whatever option in the dropdown was selected
2. Select the originally selected value from the dropdown (make the change visually and in DOM)

So far is doing none of this.

Comment: You can just use `$("#user_role").val(original_role)`

Comment: I think you linked to the wrong fiddle. It doesn't have any of that code.

Comment: But you should use `var original_role = $("#user_role").val();` Don't use the `selected` attribute, that's just for the initial selection, it's not used once the user has change the menu.

Comment: If you must use the `selected` *property*, use `.prop('selected', true)`. See [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/215552).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: @Barmar is correct. I just had to use `original_role = $('#user_role').val();` and `$('#user_role').val(original_role )` to return to its original state

Comment: `.attr('selected')` <= is the getter form of `attr()`, not the setter form.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I set to react on button click not click on select, just replace it if you want, just think this was you initial intention.

You also need to fetch `new_role`, new selected item to be removed inside click function.
And set it back to with `original_role` as Barmar  said in comment.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", () => {
  banner.toggleClass("alt")
})

var original_role = $('option:selected', '#user_role').val();
//console.log(original_role);

$('button').click(function() {
var new_role = $('option:selected', '#user_role').val();
    //console.log(new_role);
  $('#user_role option[value="'+new_role+'"]').remove();
  $("#user_role").val(original_role);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <select name="user_role" class="form-control" id="user_role">
      <option value="0">Ninguno</option>
      <option value="1">Admin</option>
      <option value="24">Secretario general</option>
      <option value="25">SecretarioExcursiones</option>
      <option value="26">Tesorería</option>
      <option value="27">Almacen</option>
      <option value="28">Coordinador</option>
      <option value="30">Reta</option>
      <option value="31">Invitado</option>
      <option value="32" selected="">Prospecto</option>
      <option value="33">Presidente</option>
      <option value="34">Eventos especiales</option>
      <option value="36">Guía</option>
      <option value="37">Soci@</option>
      <option value="38">Inivtado</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <button>
  asd
  </button>
  
</div>
```